# Express Preferences

Tags: phrase-usage, origin-unknown

Instead of   or/and  over? 
I'll take aspirin instead of ibuprofen.
I'll choose your brand over my usual.
Is that correct?

Comment: Both of those are idiomatic and would sound correct to a native speaker.

Comment: Yes to @peterG; please note, however that it would be incorrect to say "I'll take aspirin *over* ibuprofen." The sentence would need to be modified to say "I *would* [or *would rather*] take aspirin over ibuprofen." The difference is in the verb "will" which indicates future intent and "would" which indicates desire or preference. The verb phrase "will choose" in the second example also indicates preference, which is why "over" works.